# Will app downloaded by redeeming promos code be counted in Sale and Trend section in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I have given promo code of my new paid app to many people. Now in the Sale and Trend section of iTunes Connect, I saw my app has been downloaded many times. So is app downloaded by redeeming promos code counted in there or not? And if yes, is there a way to see separated number of downloads  by redeeming and by purchasing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer, if you find it ;)

Reading iTunes Connect guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html):

`When apps are purchased using promo codes, the promo code is included in earnings reports and sales reports for the transaction.`
So yes, promo codes count as normal downloads.

Comment: yes. and there is option to see paid and free (using pro code) as well. I should have looked more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently (early 2019), on [App Sore Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)'s **Sales and Trends** page:

To differentiate products that were **purchased** from products that were obtained by **redeeming a promo-code**:

1. Select the `Units` tab
2. Click on the `Transaction Type` filter

Purchases are counted as `Paid`, while promo-code redeems are counted as `Free`:

[image]

For a more precise breakdown between your different products:

3. Select `Free` or `Paid`
4. Click `Content`